# Associating skype contacts with address book

Tags: contacts, skype

After installation of new Skype version for Mac, each time I search for a contact - it gives me few choices for one person:

- the skype contact;
- the contact from address book with phone number

Is there a way to merge these two contacts into one? Maybe by adding custom field to address book or by defining same phone number in skype contact entry?

Any guides are much appreciated!

Comment: Have there been any improvements on this?

Answer (score 2):

your mac uses your Address Book as its basis for your contacts (skype is reaching in your contact list to pull people up not the other way around). So your Address Book really is the place where you emerge all of your contacts because other applications can use it to pull up contacts so you dont have to manually transfer all of your contacts to an application that might require them.

Comment: OK, but how to add a skype id to a address book contact ?

Comment: i dont know you might have to do it manually or i bet theres probably a program that dos it for you. I might even write skype asking them to add this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X Lion now allows you to specify a Skype address on your address book contacts.

Comment: Thanks! I found it. Although after adding Skype IM username to some entries, they still show up as two different contacts (the one from Skype one and the one from Address Book). Any hints?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the Skype application integrates with this Address Book field (yet).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago. Unfortunately, there is no way to merge all your contacts automatically. But and I solved manually this way.
- search for your contact on the search bar. Once you typed down his or her name, Skype will display several address book numbers for that contact and also his or her skype contact.
- Choose the number you want to ad to the skype contact. Skype will display the number and under de number it will say "save number" and a + button willl appear next to it. 
- Click the + button. It will display a pop up window giving you the chance to search for the name to which you want to link the number. Type the Skype contact name and press add number.

Like I said, it is not automatic and you'll have to ad every number to every skype contact one by one. Hope it works for you.